# How to set a Excel cell's value type to Text in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, cell, officewriter

I'm using `Softartisans OfficeWriter` to generate Excel files. The problem I have is that whenver I assign an empty string (`""` or `String.Empty`) to a cell, the cell's value type will turn out to be `Blank` instead of `Text`, which is what I want. I've tried `someCell.ValueType`, but it's a read-only property and I cannot set it to `Text` manually.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you limited to this office writer? Closedxml does all of this for excel easily.

Comment: @Saran Yes... I have to use Office Writer.

Comment: What do you need to do with the value type afterwards?

Comment: They type of the cell changes based on the value of the cell. So in order to change the cell.ValueType you have to set the value of the cell. If you set the value to a string the cell will report the value type as text. However of you set the string to "", String.Empty, or null this is the equivalent of clearing a cell in ExcelWriter.


The question I have for you is why do you need to set the ValueType directly? When you set the Cell.Value the type will automatically be detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I work for SoftArtisans

What file format are you using?
In the BIFF file format (.xls), cells assigned to an empty string will be set to a null value when the file is saved, thus causing the ValueType to return blank.

In OOXML (.xlsx) the empty string value is preserved when the file is saved, and the ValueType will return Text for any cells assigned to an empty string.
You can find more information in this KB article: http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/12/30/kb-why-do-some-blank-cells-return-different-values-in-ooxml/

Would using .xlsx files be possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to set the cell value to **'**.

That is a marker for Excel that the cell contains a text value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding escaped empty quotes to the string?

```
someCell.Value = "\"\"";
```